# Inpaint() function is not working for all kind of image to remove watermark using python opencv

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am trying to remove watermark/logo from an image. Currently using `cv2.inpaint(img,mask, 100, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)` function (of `opencv-contrib-python` library) and I am able to remove watermark from Test image 1 below. But same code is not working for Test image 2 and 3 below.

Current code:

```
import cv2 

cv2.namedWindow("Original_Image", cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)

img = cv2.imread('image10.jpeg')
mask = cv2.imread('99acres_mask.jpg', 0)


temp, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dst = cv2.inpaint(img,mask, 100, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite("removed_wm.png",dst)
```

Following Output I am getting:

Even I tried changing radius 100 in `dst = cv2.inpaint(img,mask, 100, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)`  to 3, 10, 25, 30, 50 and other values but non of them worked. Also I change flag `INPAINT_TELEA` to '`INPAINT_NS` still no luck.

Can anybody help me to remove water mark from other images as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works pretty well on Image 1. In does not work on image 2 maybe because the algorithm is too simplistic for these kind of cluttered images.

Comment: Yeah that make sense